# Cannot connect to Mariadb from Qpython terminal using Mysql Connector

Tags: mysql-python, qpython

Please could someone help this newbie. I've installed the following on my Android phone:

QPython v2.4.2

Mysql Connector v1.0.8 (via QPYPI)

MariaDBServer v10.3.8

I can connect to the server using a separate Android SQL client app, so know the server is running OK.

When I open the terminal and try to import mysql.connector, I get the below error message. I'd really appreciate some help in solving this.

Thanks in advance.

> > > import mysql.connector
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy/files/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/**init**.py", line 33, in 
> > >           from mysql.connector.connection import MySQLConnection
> > >         File "/data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy/files/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 123
> > >           except Exception, err:
> > >                           ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this myself by uninstalling Mysql Connector v1.0.8 (via QPYPI) and installing it via pip install.